# Can't find rmagick gem when required in script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've recently run into an issue with mod_passenger and gems.  I have a couple of gems install and I can find them in my /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems directory. One is will_paginate and the other is rmagick.

For some reason, when my rails app starts up, it finds will_paginate just fine, but says it can't find rmagick.  I have even tried doing this in the script/console by typing in require 'will_paginate' and require 'rmagick'.  will_paginate loads, rmagick errors out saying "MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- rmagick"

I've tried reinstalling the gem but that does not fix the issue.  I've tried restarting apache.  That doesn't fix the issue...  Any other things I can do to figure out why it's not find that particular gem?

Comment: You might want to edit your question so it is easier to find for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh... I wasn't requiring 'RMagick'. I didn't realize it was case sensitive.

require 'RMagick'

Comment: Whoa, a mixed-case `require`. That's unusual.